# get "Date" Colum from my List there it Displays DateTime.Now

Tags: development, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

```
<asp:TemplateField  HeaderText="Date" >                      
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblDat1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Date", "{0:D}")%>' ></asp:Label>   
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

I am trying to get "Date" Colum from my List there it Displays DateTime.Now
Like This

```
SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;
SPList list = web.Lists.TryGetList(DropDownListCategory.SelectedItem.Value);

SPListItem item = list.Items.Add();
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now; // date set

item["Title"] = TextBoxTitle.Text;
item["Contents"] = TextBoxContents.Text;
item["Categories"] = DropDownListCategory.SelectedItem.Value;

item["Date"] = dt; // date used
item["Authors"] = TextBoxAuthor.Text;
item["Links"] = TextBoxLinks.Text;
```

I am trying to display that DateTime from the Colum "Date" in my GrindView, are the first code right, or any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mind explaining what actually happens? Nothing appears or? If you Eval("Date") without the formatting, does it work? Anyways, you might want to convert to `DateTime` before formatting:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblDat1" runat="server" Text='<%# Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("Date")).ToString("D") %>' ></asp:Label>
```

Comment: If you have questions, instead of posting them as answers; you can comment on the Question for clarification!

Comment: @F.Aquino i get this   

String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Comment: @ArsalanAdamKhatri do u maybe now how to solve my problem?